# What happens when a question is migrated to a site that the OP isn't a member of?

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45146855/4032703) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146647/merge-sort-using-recursion) that was migrated from CS StackExchange. However, the OP doesn't have an account on Stack Overflow, just there. Will the OP still be notified about my answer? Can they accept the answer if it solved their problem?

Comment: They can see the question in their profile over on CS.SE and for the next 60 days the [migration stub](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78036/merge-sort-using-recursion?noredirect=1) will be shown on CS.SE. IIRC you get a notification of the migration. I don't expect them to get any further notifications until they confirm their account on SO but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: Comments go Weird when questions are migrated. If the user doesn't have an account, [they arrive with no attribution and can't be further migrated to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251281/cant-migrate-migrated-comments) and in some cases [can't be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/allow-deleting-comments-on-migrated-questions).